# External Data Pull: Pull more specific data or change macro based on data

Tags: vb.net, excel

This question is somewhat difficult to explain, so bear with me.

I am pulling data from a large table for my company and am trying to create a macro to make this data easier to read/understand. The data that is on the site changes every day based on what caused certain failures in our plant, which causes my macro to analyze data that isn't there or wrong cells (due to rows getting shifted/moved/added/removed). Because I don't think that was really clear, here is an example:

The macro says to select cells J5, J13, and J25. These were, when I was creating the macro, the values I wanted to be put in a list. However, when I pulled the data and ran the macro today, these values were in different spots on my sheet (the value for cell J13 is now in J12). This completely messes up all of the analysis and renders my macro / data pull useless.

Is there a way to have the macro select the data more intelligently? Perhaps have it check for the group name, then select the value from the cell next to it? I wish I could word this better... Thanks if you've gotten this far!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put... yes. Here's a code exert for looking for a groupname and getting the adjacent cell:

```
Dim Group1Range As Range
'Look in ThisWorkbook
With ThisWorkbook
    'Look in Sheet1
    With .Sheets(1)
        'Look in Column I
        With .Columns("I:I")
            'Find the text Group1
            Set Group1Range = .Find(What:="Group1").Offset(0, 1)
        End With
    End With
End With
'Indicate the address of the found range
Debug.Print Group1Range.Address
End Sub
```

Now here are ways that you can improve your question:

1. Explain how you know that cell `J13` is no longer valid, and that `J12` is now.
2. Give us some sample data.
3. Give us your code.
4. Tell us what your end result would be, possibly with an example.

Comment: Okay, I didn't want to get too specific due to company policies, but I have attached a screenshot of the data as it is reported in Excel. [Link Here](http://i.imgur.com/9i3j5.png)

I want the numbers above the word "Code" and the number next to it reported in a different column... but sometimes there will be additional rows ("REG" creates two columns sometimes) and my script still points to J13 when really the number I need is J12.

Comment: The way the data is formatted is first by WW, then by Category, then by Sub-Category. So these categories and sub-categories are repeated for many WW's. Could I set up a for loop to do this easier? Using something similar to what you just wrote?

Comment: Or, a different way of pulling the data to only include the data that I need?